# Unable to change the color of the Bootstrap 5 carousel indicators per individual slide (carousel item)

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5

In a singular carousel, some carousel items/images/slides have a dark background, and some have a light background, within the same carousel. In these cases the default white indicators are easily visible for one slide but not the next.

Is there a way to control the color of the full row of indicators (active and inactive, full opacity and half opacity) **per each slide**?

Answer (score 0):

Because the symbols are in the form of images, you cannot change their color unless you replace them with another image.
You can give them a background image to make them stand out more

```
    .carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    outline: black;
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

[image]